# Can OSGi easily be used to manage package dependencies?

Tags: java, module, osgi, modularization

I understand that OSGi can be used to manage service dependencies, that is sharing POJO instances between bundles. But say I have a library `B.jar` with compile-time dependencies on classes in my other library `A.jar`:

`ProjectA/src/com/example/awesome/A.java`:

```
package com.example.awesome;
public class A {}
```

`ProjectB/src/com/example/awesome/web/B.java`:

```
package com.example.awesome.web;
import com.example.awesome;
public class B extends A {}
```

Does OSGi have a built-in declarative way to enforce this dependency at runtime?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, using the [`Export-Package`](http://wiki.osgi.org/wiki/Export-Package) and [`Import-Package`](http://wiki.osgi.org/wiki/Import-Package) manifest headers.

If you use an automated build system, it might detect the relationship and add these headers for you. Both Maven and Gradle use [bnd](http://www.aqute.biz/Bnd/Bnd) to generate the necessary manifest headers. The bnd integration is provided by the maven-bundle-plugin and the Gradle [OSGi plugin](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/osgi_plugin.html), respectively.

Comment: Maven has the maven-bundle-plugin

Comment: Feel free to suggest an edit if you want to elaborate on my most recent edit, my experience with Maven is very limited.

Comment: Oh wait, you have enough rep to bypass peer review. Well then, feel free to edit if you like. :)

Comment: Both Maven and Gradle plugins are based on [bnd](http://www.aqute.biz/Bnd/Bnd). In addition to automatically detecting package dependencies as highlighted in the question, bnd additional detects versions properly and applies the guidelines of the Semantic Versioning whitepaper. Finally, you can use [Bndtools](http://bndtools.org) as an IDE also based on bnd.